# Actionlinks add wrong parameter when custom routes is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, actionlink

I am using this custom route to enable paging in my index method in Home controller:

```
    routes.MapRoute( _
    "HomePage", _
    "Home/Index/{page_num}", _
    New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .page_num = ""} _
    )
```

But when I navigate to any page for example page 2, actionlinks append the page number to the url:

```
Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
```

will render  _http://localhost/Home/Index/2  instead of  _http://localhost/Home/Index

But I've noticed that action methods without parameters renders correctly:
_http://localhost/Home/About

Answer (score 0):

Html.ActionLink uses page_num parameter from previous route value dictionary unless you change some parameters left to page_num.

If you had the route like below:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    "HomePage", _
    "{controller}/{action}/{page_num}", _
    New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .page_num = ""} _
    )
```

Html.ActionLink("Home","about") will clear page_num variable and you will get url like /home/about instead of /home/about/2. 
Look at this related [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901384/actionlinks-add-wrong-parameter-when-custom-routes-is-used).  Maybe it would help.

Comment: I can't understand how this route is different from the previous one, but it will make actionlinks renders the correct url for other routes which have paging eg: _http://localhost/blog/index  but still Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home") will add the page number as a parameter.